# Is keepingCapacity when using array.removeAll more performant?

Tags: swift

Assuming we have an array

```
var foo = ["bar", "baz", "qux"]
```

...and we're going to re-populate that array with the same number of elements via multiple `foo.append()` calls, after we've [removed all](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641473-removeall) elements: is there any performance advantage to keeping the existing capacity of the array?

```
// Keep the capacity
foo.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
```

vs.

```
// Don't keep the capacity
foo.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641473-removeall).

**keepCapacity**

> Pass true to request that the collection avoid releasing its storage.
>   Retaining the collection’s storage can be a useful **optimization** when
>   you’re planning to *grow* the collection *again*. The default value is
>   false.

---

So the answer is **yes** i guess.

Comment: +1 -- though I do wonder how "optimization" equates to "performance", in this context. Perhaps there's less memory churn (i.e., no need to allocate memory during each append)?

Comment: [Current implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift#L1262) kinda indicates that the buffer remains the same. Though is possible (but iMO unlikely) for this implementation to change.